# Pattern recognition

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning

I am trying to have *Mathematica* come up with a simplified version of a real pattern. For the moment I'm trying with handwritten digits, but eventually I want to apply it to more complex photographs.

My first attempt (very inefficient):

1) I take a sample image, for instance the number 7

```
seven = ExampleData[{"MachineLearning", "MNIST"}, "TestData"][[7300, 1]];
```

the image is [image]

2) I extract the corners (the order of this list is by "weight")

```
corners = ImageCorners[seven];    
HighlightImage[seven, corners]
```

3) I connect the dots and make an image out of all possible permutations

```
candidates = 
  Image[#, ImageSize -> {28, 28}, ColorSpace -> "Grayscale"]& /@ 
    Graphics /@ Line /@ Permutations@corners;
```

4) I compare the grayscale values to the actual image and I pick the one with largest correlation

```
index = 
  Module[{l = ListCorrelate[#, ImageData@seven]& /@ ImageData /@ candidates}, 
    Position[l, Max[l]]][[1, 1]];
Row[{seven, candidates[[index]]}]
```

This returns which order of the corners yields the best approximation to the initial shape (but there are several different orderings leading to the same image, which is one of the inefficiencies).

This "works", but there must be a better way of making an $n$-segment approximation of a given shape.

Any ideas?

EDIT: I am attaching a sample image, as requested by @belisarius

Comment: Could you please include the original image? (For pre-v10 users)

Comment: Some time ago I programmed [a handwritten digits classifier](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2013/08/26/classification-of-handwritten-digits/) using SVD over matrices with rows representing images of a digit. (For each digit I had a separate matrix.) The basis vectors of the SVD for each digit are used to approximate the digit image that has to be recognized. I think the SVD basis vectors might be what you want, if you have multiple images/versions of the pattern you want to approximate.

Comment: A simpler approach is to cluster the (preprocessed) images and find the mean image for each digit.

Comment: This is definitely a job for PCA or related methods!

Comment: A question to consider is what exactly is the class of examples for which a method is sought? Digit images that come close to binary images might be amenable to some simple tactics. Are they representative of the full class of inputs? If so, erosion or filling approaches might make sense.

Comment: Indeed, once I understand how to do this more efficiently I am planning on using erosion and separating the colors by similarity.

Comment: A related approach, suitable for binary or close-to-binarized images, is to use "fast marching" to move in a few pixels from the boundary, in effect making the black part thinner. There is code I used on a different but related problem [here](http://blog.wolfram.com/2010/12/07/navigating-the-blenheim-maze/). (The point in that case was to move through a maze but one could rearrange so as to tighten the passageway instead.)